# simple beginner search program using arrays in javascript, issue with displaying

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I am creating a simple search program that searches for my name block of text. The issue I am having is at the end, when I place the letters in the array, they seem to come out a single character on each line, rather than uniformly in one single block of text. Can anyone point out the discrepancy?

```
var text = "hah hah Aaron hah hah Aaron\
hah hah hah hah hoh Aaron hah hah hah hah\
Aaron Aaron Aaron hah";
var myName = "Aaron";
var hits = [];

for (var i =0; i< text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] === "A") {
       for (var j = i; j <(myName.length + i); j++){
        hits.push(text[j]);
       } 
    }
}
if (hits === 0) {
    console.log ("Your name wasn't found!");
}
else {
    console.log(hits);
}
```

Comment: Suppose that you have a String "hah hah Adam hah hah hah Aaron", wouldn't your test be wrong because it discovers the "A" from "Adam" before it discovers the "A" from "Aaron"? Is there any reason why you're not using the indexOf() method?

Comment: You should search the topics [explode in PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp) and iterate the returned array to check if **Aaron** or whatever you want to search. (I am assuming that you are searching Aaron as a seperate word, not a Substring)

Answer (score 0):

The reason of "letter by letter" behaviour is that variable *hits* contains an array of single letters from all the matches.

You either need to call **join** method on array with letters from one name found, or use something more advanced instead of cycles. For example, `text.match(/Aaron/g)` will return an array of all names matched.

Answer (score -2):

I think this search program is much more valid:

```
var text = "Blah blah blah blah blah blah Eric \
blah blah blah Eric blah blah Eric blah blah \
blah blah blah blah blah Eri Epic Erics☺n"
var name = "Eric"
var x=0;
var y=0

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  x=0;
  for (var j = i; j < name.length + i; j++) {
    if (text[j] === name[j-i]) {
      x++;
      if(x === name.length) {
        y++
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log("Found "+y+" times")
```