# Use of string.length + counter variable

Tags: javascript, string, function

I'm new to programming and am currently learning javascript on [CodeAcademy](https://www.codecademy.com). This code below is from a tutorial where the program will search a string to look for a name. The program will loop through the array, compare each letter to the first letter of your name, and if it sees that letter:
It will push that letter and all the letters that follow it to an array, stopping when the number of letters it pushes are equal to the number of letters in your name.

What I don't understand is the line : `for (var j = i; j < (myName.length + i); j++)`
why does `j <(myName.length + i)` and not `j<(myName.length)`? If the letter "E" of "Eric" is the 25th character in the string, wouldn't `j<(myName.length + i) = j<("4" + "25")` which is wrong as it the correct code should be `j<("4")` where 4 is the length of the name Eric.

I've tried running the code with `j<(myName.length)` but it fails to work and I cant seem to understand why.

```
text = "Blah blah blah blah blah blah Eric \
        blah blah blah Eric blah blah Eric blah blah \
        blah blah blah blah blah Eric";

var myName = "Eric";
var hits = [];

// Look for "E" in the text
for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] == "E") {
        // If we find it, add characters up to the length of my name to the array
        for(var j = i; j < (myName.length + i); j++) {
            hits.push(text[j]);
        }
    }
}

if (hits.length === 0) {
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
} else {
    console.log(hits);
}
```

Comment: I saw this piece of code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996731/simple-beginner-search-program-using-arrays-in-javascript-issue-with-displaying Where does it come from?

Comment: Suppose that you have a String "hah hah Eddy hah hah hah Eric", wouldn't your test be wrong because it discovers the "E" from "Eddy" before it discovers the "E" from "Eric"? Is there any reason why you're not using the indexOf() method?

Comment: The code if from a javascript tutorial in CodeAcademy. The link is http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-XEDZA/0/1?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661     And yep, the string would return Eddy before Eric.It's still a beginner tutorial so i havent learnt about indexOf() yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your inner loop, you are doing this:

```
for(var j = i;
```

When  condition `if (text[i] == "E") {` gets satisfied, the value of `i` is very high (30).

Now, **when you do this:**

```
for(var j = i; j < (myName.length); j++) {
```

you are basically doing this -

```
 for(var j = 30; j < 4; j++) {
```

So the loop never starts; as the boundary condition is not satisfied.

But **when you do this:**

```
for(var j = i; j < (myName.length+i); j++) {
```

then you are doing this:

```
for(var j = 30; j < (30+4) ; j++) {
```

Hence everything works, the way it should.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you will not use code above in your future projects :)

```
text = 'Blah blah blah blah blah blah Eric blah blah blah Eric blah blah Eric blah blah blah blah blah blah blah Eric';
var hits = text.match(/Eric/g) || [];
if (hits.length) {
  console.log('Your name was found ' + hits.length + ' times');
}
else {
  console.log('Your name wasn\'t found!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the code you presented works properly and you don't understand why? If so, here's my explanation:

The both `i` and `j` mark the position in `text`. `i` is initialized as zero in `for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {` . The way a loop works is that it will evaluate `i` based on the condition `i < text.length;`, if it is true, then it will run the code block, perform your iterator (`i++` which mean add 1 to i), and then start the loop over by evaluating the condition again.

You'll notice that `j` is initialized as `i` instead of zero. So what happens is that if the letter at position `i` of string `text` is "E", then it will start another loop, setting `j` to `i` (so 25 in the case above), and then iterate forward the length of your name.. And I believe that this condition is what confuses you:

`for(var j = i; j < (myName.length + i); j++) {`

So let me walk through what will happen in this loop:

at first it will set `j` to the current position in `text`, which conveniently `i` knows. So let's say `i` has reached 25. So the loop sets `j` to 25 via `i`. Now since we want the *next* four character, and not the *first* four characters, of `text`, the condition is set to `j < (myName.length + i)` .

Since "Eric" is four characters, it will add `text[25]` , `text[26]`, `text[27]`, and `text[28]` to `hits`. If you go look at `texts`, you'll notice that the 25th through 28th letter are (supposed to be) your name.